# How do I add an object at a specific location in an array with multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

This is my Object:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "1709408412689",
        "name": "WB1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1709408412690",
                "name": "WA X",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1709408412687",
                        "name": "B-Plan",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408606635",
                        "name": "Lph 1",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1709408412691",
                "name": "WA 1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679357",
                        "name": "B-Plan",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679358",
                        "name": "Lph 1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679359",
                        "name": "Lph 2",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "1709308679359",
                                "name": "Lph 2.2",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I'm getting these 4 Info:

```js
{newID: 1509408679357
name: 'INSERTHERE',
typeToInsert: 'before' (before or after)
placeToInsert: '1709408679358' }
```

Now I would like to insert a new object before (typeToInsert: 'before') the Object with ID: '1709408679358' (placeToInsert).

I've tried a few things, but because the objects can be nested x times, I thought I had to do it with a recursive function. Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Expected Output:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "1709408412689",
        "name": "WB1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1709408412690",
                "name": "WA X",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1709408412687",
                        "name": "B-Plan",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408606635",
                        "name": "Lph 1",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1709408412691",
                "name": "WA 1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679357",
                        "name": "B-Plan",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1509408679357",
                        "name": "INSERTHERE",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679358",
                        "name": "Lph 1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1709408679359",
                        "name": "Lph 2",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "1709308679359",
                                "name": "Lph 2.2",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code first recursively searches for the correct array to insert the new object into.

We check if the array has a child with the necessary id, and if not, we use `reduce` to locate a descendent array that contains an object with that id.

Then, we use splice to insert the object. If we're inserting after instead of before, we have to add 1 to the target index after locating the entry to insert after. This is achieved concisely by type coercion of true/false to 1/0.

```js
const data = [{"id":"1709408412689","name":"WB1","children":[{"id":"1709408412690","name":"WA X","children":[{"id":"1709408412687","name":"B-Plan","children":[]},{"id":"1709408606635","name":"Lph 1","children":[]}]},{"id":"1709408412691","name":"WA 1","children":[{"id":"1709408679357","name":"B-Plan","children":[]},{"id":"1709408679358","name":"Lph 1","children":[]},{"id":"1709408679359","name":"Lph 2","children":[{"id":"1709308679359","name":"Lph 2.2","children":[]}]}]}]}]

const update = {newID: 1509408679357, name: 'INSERTHERE', typeToInsert: 'before', placeToInsert: '1709408679358'}

const getTargetArray = arr => arr.some(({id}) => id===update.placeToInsert) ? 
  arr : arr.reduce((a, {children}) => a ?? getTargetArray(children), null)

const targetArray = getTargetArray(data)

targetArray.splice(
  targetArray.findIndex(({id}) => id === update.placeToInsert) 
    + (update.typeToInsert === 'after'), 
  0, 
  {id: update.newID, name: update.name, children: []}
)

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it only works sometimes. And sometimes the object is inserted in the wrong place.

Comment: @RKRdev please add to your question an exact example that uses my code but which produces the wrong result. Perhaps there was something about your question that I did not understand

Comment: Updated my question...Object should be inserted second to last. Before "1709408749586" but its at the second position in childrens.

Comment: @RKRdev you're right, there was a bug. It's now fixed.

Comment: what was the Bug ?
The Line with update.typeToInsert === 'before' ? 0 : 1, should do the same like (update.typeToInsert === 'after') or ?

Comment: That is only line that has changed. There was an operator precedence issue with the previous version